How to pick masters topic?
I asked a professor I had taken a class with to be my supervisor for my project in 1-2 years. He agreed. I overlooked that, typically, students apply for projects directly with professors or proposition them with an outline for a project (our project component is similar to a master's project (but on a smaller scale with a 3 month timeline)). (I can provide more info if needed, but typically it is similar to a publication with a period of testing/data collection and then a conclusion that supports a thesis).
I directly asked him to be my supervisor. He agreed and has offered that I propose some topics and he will provide readings to me.
I am a bit overwhelemed with topic research, but I am interested in starting early and establishing a foundation for my chosen topic ahead of time, as the timeline proposed by the university is far too short. I recognize that he was immensely generous in agreeing, so I do not want to bother him.
Would any students who have completed this process already inform me about what timeline to expect and how they chose a topic to focus on throughout their undergrad?
Thank you. (I am in computer science)

Talk to your professor about this exact issue.


publication with a period of testing/data collection and then a
conclusion that supports a thesis

This is very little to go on, but generally speaking, try to choose something that is actually of interest to you. This will help you through the inevitable roadblocks. Maybe some other coursework of yours got you interested in an area of your field? In my experience, the data collection is the hard part. If you are required to gather data yourself and are not allowed to use datasets that are available (many institutions offer free access to datasets for research), try to avoid anything where you need human participants, this is a time sink that you can not control.
Also, realize that "No" or "hard to say" is a totally acceptable answer to your research question. You don't have to publish it. It's about you learning to apply the scientific method.

I recognize that he was immensely generous in agreeing, so I do not want to bother him

Firstly, he was not. This is literally his job. Nothing wrong with respecting his time, but he is doing his job.
Talk to other students that allready did their project or the students' representation of your program to see other people's opinion and experiences. I found it useful to see examples. This really comes down to how your specific institution, what "a research project" means in terms of size and depth. I understand not wanting to waste the Professor's time, but most prefer you asking instead of never submitting anything or something completely off the mark due to not understanding the task at hand.

certainly, thank you for your insight. I'm planning on getting into contact with some TA's and gleaning some insight from them. Overall, it's very daunting, but I appreciate your reply. What did you study?

@mike Stack Exchange discourages using comments to chat. But I'll interpret your question as a clarification question, so you can gauge if my experiences apply to you. I did try my hand at several programs, including stem and humanities. So I did experience how different the culture in the fields are. I have a bachelors of sociology and a computer science master.
